# Index and Slice a Generator in Python

Tags: python, generator

Lets say I have a generator function that looks like this:

```
def fib():
    x,y = 1,1
    while True:
        x, y = y, x+y
        yield x
```

Ideally, I could just use *fib()[10]* or *fib()[2:12:2]* to get indexes and slices, but currently I have to use itertools for these things. I can't use a generator for a drop in replacement for lists.

I believe the solution will be to wrap *fib()* in a class:

```
class Indexable(object):
    ....

fib_seq = Indexable(fib())
```

What should *Indexable* look like to make this work?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
import itertools

class Indexable(object):
    def __init__(self,it):
        self.it = iter(it)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.it
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        try:
            return next(itertools.islice(self.it,index,index+1))
        except TypeError:
            return list(itertools.islice(self.it,index.start,index.stop,index.step))
```

You could use it like this:

```
it = Indexable(fib())
print(it[10])
#144
print(it[2:12:2])
#[610, 1597, 4181, 10946, 28657]
```

Notice that `it[2:12:2]` does not return `[3, 8, 21, 55, 144]` since the iterator had already advanced 11 elements because of the call to `it[10]`.

**Edit:** If you'd like `it[2:12:2]` to return `[3, 8, 21, 55, 144]` then perhaps use this instead:

```
class Indexable(object):

    def __init__(self, it):
        self.it = iter(it)
        self.already_computed = []

    def __iter__(self):
        for elt in self.it:
            self.already_computed.append(elt)
            yield elt

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        try:
            max_idx = index.stop
        except AttributeError:
            max_idx = index
        n = max_idx - len(self.already_computed) + 1
        if n > 0:
            self.already_computed.extend(itertools.islice(self.it, n))
        return self.already_computed[index]
```

This version saves the results in `self.already_computed` and uses those results
if possible. Otherwise, it computes more results until it has sufficiently many
to return the indexed element or slice.

Comment: To exhibit the same behavior as a list, __getitem__ would need to rewind the generator. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: I don't know if there's any way to do that, easy or not, but the Indexable class could just store all the already-generated items in a list. Then `__getitem__` would pull the numbers directly from the list, after first advancing the generator if necessary.

Comment: That's a handy solution. It looks like there are two ways to accomplish my question, using a result cache like you have or copying the iterator. It is just a trade-off between using more memory or cpu.

Answer (score 2):

To slice generator you can use `islice` function from `itertools`

```
from itertools import islice

for i in islice(generator, 5):
    # Will be taken first 5 elems

for i in islice(generator, 5, None):
    # Will be taken everything starting at 5th
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a 1-use slice than you could simply use the method written by ~unutbu. If you need to slice multiple times you would have to store all the intermediate values so you can "rewind" the iterator. Since iterators can iterate anything it would not have a rewind method by default.

Also, since a rewinding iterator has to store every intermediate result it would (in most cases) have no benefit over simply doing `list(iterator)`

Basically... you either don't need an iterator, or you're not specific enough about the situation.

Comment: `list(fib())` will give you a MemoryError eventually

Comment: How about the case where I want the 6,000th fibonacci number. The clearest way to express this is fib[6000] even though there are several ways to get it, they just aren't expressed as elegantly.

Comment: My point is, in nearly all real-life situations you would make the object itself sliceable instead of implementing slicing at the generator.

If you don't, it would be impossible to optimize the function call properly. For any large fibonacci number you wouldn't want to generate the entire list just to get a number, you would use a method to "guess" the number.

Answer (score 0):

So based off the code from ~unutbu and adding in a little itertools.tee:

```
import itertools

class Indexable(object):
    def __init__(self, it):
        self.it = it

    def __iter__(self):
        self.it, cpy = itertools.tee(self.it)
        return cpy

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        self.it, cpy = itertools.tee(self.it)
        if type(index) is slice:
            return list(itertools.islice(cpy, index.start, index.stop, index.step))
        else:
            return next(itertools.islice(cpy, index, index+1))
```

Comment: Right, but this option burns CPU every time you use it. For lists that are too long to store in ~unutbu's `already_computed` the CPU time required here is likely to be excessive too.

Comment: I think it also might come down to the complexity of the generator, if the code inside the generator is CPU heavy using already_computed is the best option but perhaps if it is simple like xrange just recomputing it is better.

Comment: Doesn't itertools.tee internally just store results so it can replay them later? It has no way of knowing whether it can copy the iterator either; consider an iterator over incoming network requests, or something.

Answer (score 0):

For small cases (e.g. you are only ever going to use at most the first 20 Fiboonacci numbers), where it isn't worth adding a full class, the simplest solution is to convert islice output to a list:

```py
from itertools import islice

list(islice(fib(), 20))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is ~unutbu's answer modified to subclass list. Obviously abuse such as `append`, `insert` etc. will produce weird results!

you do get `__str__` and `__repr__` methods for free though

```
import itertools
class Indexable(list):
    def __init__(self,it):
        self.it=it
    def __iter__(self):
        for elt in self.it:
            yield elt
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        try:
            max_idx=index.stop
        except AttributeError:
            max_idx=index
        while max_idx>=len(self):
            self.append(next(self.it))
        return list.__getitem__(self,index)
```

Comment: Lists are too different from what we want for this to be useful. Don't do this.

Comment: People who have this problem, I suppose.