# Index through a generator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, indexing, generator

Would it be possible to index through a generator function?

For example, say I have a function like this:

```
def foo():
    x = 9
    yield x
    yield x+1
```

I understand that when calling the `next()` method on the generator function `foo()`, the output would be `9` and then `10`. Would it be possible to go straight to the second output; `10` ? I haven't thought of how to do this, except by indexing through the generator function which I also don't know how to do.

Comment: yield only x+1 ?

Comment: Potentially also helpful: [Index and Slice a Generator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2322642)

Comment: @sahasrara62 well would I be able to output that with out having to output x by it self first, without having to rearrange the yield statements to having x+1 being first and x being second?

Comment: `secondValue = next(itertools.islice(foo(),1))`  or `_,secondValue = foo()`